# Laravel: run a command line program when package is installed

Tags: php, laravel, compilation, package, laravel-5

I am attempting to create a Laravel 5 package that lets me manipulate images, including optimize their file size. Ideally I would like to do something like the following:

```
Image::scale('myImage.png', 300, 300)->rotate(90)->optimize()->save('newImage.png');
```

For the "optimize" step, I wish to use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org/)

So long as pngquant is installed, this isn't too hard -- parse the input to be sure it's safe then pass it to the `exec()` command.

The challenge is **installing** pngquant. My current solution involves including the compiled programs as part of the package, like so:

```
/vendor
    /stevendesu
        /image-manipulator
            /bin
                /windows
                    pngquant.exe
                /mac
                    pngquant
                /linux
                    Uhh.... /src ?
            /src
                ImageManipualtorServiceProvider.php
```

For Windows and Mac this works - I detect the operating system and call the appropriate binary:

```
if( substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) == 'WIN' )
    exec( dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/bin/windows/pngquant.exe ' . $parameters );
else if( substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) == 'MAC' )
    exec( dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/bin/mac/pngquant' . $parameters );
else
    exec( '.... I need to compile pngquant!!!' );
```

For Linux there is no single binary I can include - it must be compiled from source... At least as far as I'm aware (if I compile it on a Linux machine and copy it to another Linux machine, will it just work?)

I know that I can compile from source in PHP by just calling `chdir($sourceDir); exec('make');`, however I don't want to have to run this the first time someone attempts to use pngquant and finds the binary file is missing. I'd rather compile from source when the package is first installed.

Having installed a package before, and having made my own, I realized that the `php artisan vendor:publish` command would be almost perfect for this. It copies config files and migration files and it's run once - when the package is installed.

However I don't know how to hook into this command to run `exec('make');`

I tried the following in my service provider and it didn't work:

```
public function boot()
{
    // Publish config file
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../config/image-manipulator.php' => config_path('image-manipulator.php'),
    ]);

    // Detect operating system... If Linux, we'll need to compile our
    // dependencies from source
    $substring = strtolower( substr( PHP_OS, 0, 3 ) );
    if( $substr != 'win' && $substr != 'mac' ) {
        // Compile pngquant
        if(!file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__) . '/bin/linux/pngquant/pngquant'))) {
            $returnVal = exec('which gcc');
            if(empty($returnVal)) {
                // Error - gcc not installed
            }

            $returnVal = exec('ldconfig -p | grep "libpng"');
            if(empty($returnVal)) {
                // Error - libpng not installed
            }

            $returnVal = exec('ldconfig -p | grep "libz"');
            if(empty($returnVal)) {
                // Error - zlib not installed
            }

            $returnVal = exec('cd ' . dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/bin/linux/pngquant/src && make');
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I get this code to run once when the package is installed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to do this right now.

Perhaps just build an artisan command in your package and just tell developers to run your command during the installation process.

Documentation : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands

Comment: That sounds like it will suit my requirements perfectly (building an artisan command) - I'm just now sure how to do it. I'll try researching it a bit, or if you can then please update your answer with an example for how to create an artisan command. If it works then I'll accept, otherwise I'll comment with the new issues

Comment: This tutorial is outdated a little, but might help - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/your-one-stop-guide-to-laravel-commands--net-30349

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to accept. Had a busy week.

Comment: Thanks. This issue annoys me in laravel too. I'm going to try to build a pull request into laravel to allow to handle this. So hopefully at some point this gets fixed.